# Copy CiviVolunteer volunteer needs when creating a repeating event

Tags: civievent, civivolunteer

When creating an event I am able to set the volunteer needs according to the regular schedule. If I set the event to repeat then I'd like it to copy those volunteer needs for each repeating event. Basically, I want a weekly volunteer schedule. Right now, none of the volunteer needs from CiviVolunteer copy for the repeating events, although you are able to edit each event's volunteer needs separately, which I'd like to keep.
 Does anyone know if this possible? If not, any tips on how to develop it? I am a novice programmer, so perhaps I could try to develop this functionality. Thanks much!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find all you need about this question at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-37

Note also that CiviVolunteer 2.0 beta is planned for a release on September (2015) - https://civicrm.org/blogs/ginkgofjg/civivolunteer-20-whats-in-the-works.

Comment: I assume this never made it to CiviVolunteer 2.x?  Just installed 2.2 and disappointed to find that volunteer info doesn't get propagate when an event is repeated.  We're running a Nightshelter every night for 4 months so repeating events is essential.

Comment: You seems to be right. If it's a feature that you really need, you should consider contacting the author of the extension (Ginkgo Street Labs) and contract them or do a donation to help make it happen.